# Firebase REST API POST (push) unique id for child item as well as top item

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app users can create "chains" and then other users can add "links" to chains. When a user creates a new chain they create a link with it (there should be no such thing as a chain with no links).

So I want to do something like this:

```
curl -X POST -d '{ "1": "First link for this chain" }' 'https://myapp.firebaseio.com/chains.json'
```

Which will create a unique timestamp id for the new chain, but the problem is that I also want a unique timestamp id for the the first link, instead of the "1", so that it fits in nicely with the rest of the links that will be pushed on later.

I gather that multiple requests can be all put together using the JavaScript SDK etc, but how do I do this with the REST API?

**EDIT**: I didn't mention I want to do it all in one request, rather than create an empty chain as one request and then push the first link on with another request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call POST on the REST API, the Firebase server generates a unique ID. But for platforms where there is a Firebase SDK (e.g. JavaScript, iOS, Android), the unique ID that is generated by the Firebase client.

*The unique IDs that Firebase generates are also often called "push IDs", because they are generated by the JavaScript `push()` method. To learn more about them, read this [article about push IDs](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-02-11-firebase-unique-identifiers.html).*

A snippet that generates two push IDs (in JavaScript syntax):

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/chains');
var newChain = ref.push();
console.log(newChain.key());
var newLink = newChain.push();
console.log(newLink.key());
newLink.set('First link for this chain');
```

That last line is the only time in this snippet that any call is made to the Firebase servers. All other operations are client-side.

Since you are not using a Firebase SDK, you cannot use the JavaScript snippet above. But you *can* do the same thing as the client does in the above snippet: generate one of the push IDs client-side and then send a single command to the REST API.

The [code for generating push IDs in JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/mikelehen/3596a30bd69384624c11) was published by Firebase on Github:

Comment: perfect, i did think it might be easier if i just generate my own UIDs anyway, so i'll just do that - i don't think they even need to be the same kind of UID as the firebase ones.

Comment: i'm finding there's quite a few things that are harder without the SDKs, going to post another question about email/password auth with REST API now...

Comment: The SDKs are indeed not the simple wrappers that you may initially think. They do quite a bit of work and contain a lot of the code that makes Firebase what it is.

Comment: that's a shame :( i'm trying to use it in unity - i assumed i'd be able to do everything with just the rest api, and not need a unity sdk