# Create new child in Firebase with unique push ID using Firebase Web CMS

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to insert new child to a node in Firebase that has unique push ID.

This can be achieved using REST request -x POST, but repeating this tasks over and over again could be exhausting. It's overwhelming to have to use REST requests just for creating small sample data structure.

Does Firebase provide a way to insert a new child with unique ID directly in the Firebase Dashboard CMS?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34810085/firebase-rest-api-post-push-unique-id-for-child-item-as-well-as-top-item and the article linked there on how to generate your own unique IDs that follow Firebase's scheme. But any other scheme would work equally fine.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for your reference, I'll use the Ruby / PHP version in Terminal.
Any plan to implement this in the Firebase dashboard CMS in the future?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you'd like to see implemented. You're calling our REST full API. If you use `POST` the server will generate a key for you. If you use `PUT`, you can specify your own key. If you use `PATCH` you can even specify multiple children, but you will have to generate your own keys.